# Blazor project publish doesn't create DLL files

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I have two separate .NET6.0 projects for back-end and front-end. Backend with C# can be published just fine. Front-end is written with Blazor. When I choose publish, it goes through the process without errors or exceptions. It also builds files in the *bin>Release>net6.0* directory just fine but doesn't create any of the DLL files in my chosen directory for publish. In that directory, it just creates *wwwroot*, *libman.json* and *web.config* as you can see in the image.
Where can be the cause of the problem?

[image: in the publish directory]

Comment: Have you looked inside the wwwroot directory...?

Comment: @TGnat yes, it's just static files, typical of wwwroot: _content, -framework, css, jquery, js, ...

Comment: The dlls, and such, should be in the wwwroot\\_framework directory.

Comment: @TGnat thank you. Yes, there are DLLs in wwwroot\_framework directory but when I build the project, there are many DLL files directly in the main build output directory, beside wwwroot folder. Shouldn't it be similar when I publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blazor web assembly app is a static app so it will have much static files, the logic codes you wrote in `.razor` will be packaged into `your_project_name.dll` in `wwwroot\_framework`.

[image]
[image]

Then when we need to [host the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#standalone-deployment), we need to find a static file server to serve the app. For example, IIS. When publish the static app, we need to create a website and set the website point to the publish folder which containing `wwwroot folder and web.config` file. Then make sure the IIS had installed `url rewrite` module since it's a static website. After installing the module, we will see the default rewrite rule like this:

[image]
[image]